# how to get a link to a file with https in json in drf

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, https

I have app with api on `drf`.

I installed the `ssl certificate` on the site and when I try to get the file I get an error:

The page at site:

> https://www.example.com was loaded over Https, but requested an insecure resource [http://api.example.com/……](http://api.example.com/%E2%80%A6%E2%80%A6)

I think the problem is that with a get request in json, my link starts with http...

How can i solve this problem and get file link starting with https ?? or is it something else?

Json from get request:

```
{
  "id": 50,
  "name": "Образец заполнения книги учета доходов",
  "category": "Бухгалтерия и налоги",
  "count_download": 0,
  "type_doc": "xls",
  "screenshot": "http://api.example.com/media/screenshot/%.png",
  "add_time": "2023-03-27",
  "pdffile": "http://api.example.com/media/pdf_docs/%.pdf"
}
```

I think
perhaps it is necessary to somehow make a proxy server, but I don’t understand how…

I have nginx in container

My nginx.conf

```
server {

    server_name api.example.com;

    listen 80;
    root /var/html/;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    root /var/html/;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 10m;

   location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
       root /var/www/certbot;
   }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }


    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /docs/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/redoc.html;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
         autoindex on;
    }
  

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000/admin/;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/html/;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    # server_tokens off;
    # client_max_body_size 10m;

}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    root /var/html/;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
       root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
      }
}
```

Comment: Is your application being served behind a reverse proxy (Nginx, Apache, etc)?

Comment: I have nginx in container